# Improving speed of code computing number of nonrepeating partitions

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, combinatorics, partitions

I need to answer the following for a number of parameters: How many ways can the integer $k$ be written as a sum of $n$ different integers ranging from $1$ to $m$?

My initial attempt was the following function:

```
NumberOfWays[k_, n_, m_] := 
  Count[Map[Length, 
    Map[DeleteDuplicates, 
     IntegerPartitions[k, {n}, Range[m]]]], 
   n];
```

This works, but becomes very slow as the parameters get big. I then thought I might do it using a generating function and attempted the following:

```
GenFuncy[m_] := Product[1 + y*x^j, {j, 1, m}];
NumberOfWays2[k_, n_, m_] := Coefficient[GenFuncy[m], x^k*y^n];
```

Again this works, but surprisingly (to me) it is even slower.

Is there any way I can speed these functions up, or maybe another faster way to do the calculation altogether?

Comment: Capitalized `I` is reserved for the imaginary unit, and `N` is a function meant for making exact numbers inexact; consider using different variables.

Comment: Anyway: look up `QPochhammer[]`.

Comment: @belisarius I've looked at the docs for `IntegerPartitions` and I don't see how it can be more useful (i.e. how to use only unique parts); I'm using all function parameters except the one that specifies to the `m` first partitions, which I don't see how can be useful. Any pointers?

Comment: @jorgen Sorry, I misunderstood your question

Comment: Have you read this?:  http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.10

Comment: @J. M. I assume you mean using `Qpochhammer[]` instead of my `GenFuncy`? If so I don't think this will speed it up since the construction of the latter is not what takes time - unless Mathematica can find coefficients of inbuilt functions must faster (I'm having trouble testing this right now; e.g. `Expand[QPochhammer[-x*y, x, 5]]` doesn't work)

Comment: This is a well-studied problem. Learn about multiply-restricted partitions, avail yourself of math.stackexchange.com  if you have difficulty with the subject, then pick a technique and implement it...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I did now, I don't immediately see how it can be used since I need the partition into exactly $n$ distinct parts, while the closest I can find on the page is partitions into at most $n$ distinct parts, or into (non-distinct) parts from a given set?

Comment: Okay, I didn't see a direct answer there either but I thought it might help.

Comment: Well, what I had in mind was for you to use `SeriesCoefficient[]` on `QPochhammer[]`…

Comment: @J. M. I must admit I'd like to see your solution.  jorgen, this is not a good solution but at least it is faster than your `NumberOfWays2`:  `NumberOfWays3[k_, n_, m_] := {k, n} /. CoefficientRules[GenFuncy[m], {x, y}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, yes it is! In fact on my laptop it is sometimes slower than my `NumberOfWays[k_, n_, m_]` but sometimes much faster, not in a pattern that I can discern yet.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I'll probably post when I'm in front of a computer again, but the general idea is similar to what OP did for the generating function: starting with, say, `QPochhammer[-x y, x, 5]`, use `SeriesCoefficient[]` to get the coefficient of `x^k`, and then use `Coefficient[]` to get the appropriate coefficient of `y`.

Comment: @J. M. Makes sense; I'm having some trouble using those functions on `QPochhammer`, probably doing something wrong so I'll be curious to see it

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If you write your solution as an answer (and no one comes up with an even faster one within a reasonable time) I'll accept it - most of the time it's _much_ faster than my two solutions.

Comment: Okay, but it's enumerating all coefficients which is far from ideal.  I'll only answer-ize it if nothing better turns up soon.

Comment: Just expand your product before getting desired coeff., should aid performance, e.g. `Coefficient[Product[1 + y*x^j, {j, 1, #3}] // Expand, 
   x^#1*y^#2] &[k, n, m]`

Comment: Give `SeriesCoefficient[
   QPochhammer[-x y, x, #3], {x , 0, #1}, {y, 0, #2}] &[k, n, m]` a whirl... a one-shot test using `{k = 107, n = 11, m = 100}` was nearly order of mag. faster than *NumberOfWays3* and/or straight `Coefficient` on the *expanded* product (the latter two ~ in speed in q&d tests.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems pretty quick, particularly on larger cases / larger *k*, e.g.
`451, 29, 101` finishes in a few seconds on the loungebook.

N.B. - I have *not* tested this exhaustively, just thrown together from ideas...

```
If[Min[#3, #1 - Tr@Range@(#2 - 1)] < 0, 0, 
   SeriesCoefficient[QPochhammer[-x y, x, Min[#3, #1 - Tr@Range@(#2 - 1)]], 
                     {x , 0, #1}, {y, 0, #2}]] &[n, k, m]
```

UPDATE:

This seems to be very fast, particularly on larger cases. n.b.: posted with testing in progress, I'd like to prove correctness, but so far empirical testing matches prior methods, and appears faster than answers prior on large cases...

```
myDP[n_, k_, m_] := If[n < Binomial[k + 1, 2] || m < k, 0, 
                       SeriesCoefficient[QBinomial[m, k, q], {q, 0, n - Binomial[k + 1, 2]}]]
```

For a huge case of *{n, k, m} = {5050, 100, 5050}* this took a fraction of a second on the loungebook to return the result of 1 (for this case, there would be ~$2.74235\times 10^{68}$ partitions generated for any of the partition massaging methods like the OP's *NumberOfWays*, making use of these absurd for anything other than minimal cases.) The neat follow-up solution from *KennyColnago* took (unsure - aborted it after 5 minutes, monitoring progress indicated over an hour would be needed, figure 10X faster or so for both on a workstation...) for the same case - but I'd prefer to perhaps have his benchmark post extended with results on his hardware for a fair comparison.

Update 2:
A further optimization, taking advantage of the symmetry of the gaussian polynomial:

```
myDPc[n_, k_, m_] := 
 Module[{mn = Binomial[k + 1, 2], mx = (k - k^2 + 2 k m)/2},
  If[mn <= n <= mx && m >= k,
     SeriesCoefficient[QBinomial[Min[n - Binomial[k, 2], m], k, q],
                       {q, 0, If[n > (mn + mx)/2, mx - n, n - mn]}],0]];
```

On an exhaustive search for all valid *n* for *{k,m}={45,60}* this was over 4X faster than *myDP*, and for large cases (e.g., *{n,k,m}={18775, 50, 400}* it was over 20,000X faster than *myDP*.

There's an additional optimization possible that might be advantageous when searching ranges of {n,k,m}: for any given *{n,k,m}*, by symmetry of the Q-Binomial, there's a dual of *{n', k',m}* where *n'* and *k'* are simple transformations of *n* and *k* that has precisely the same polynomial. Memoization on that can about double the performance for such searches.

Update 3 2015/08/20: Added an optimization (in edited *myDPc* above) for larger *k*, resulting in over 2 orders of magnitude performance boost to e.g. *{n,k,m}={5100,100,5100}* and about three orders of magnitude boost to *{n,k,m}={12000,154,12000}*.

I think I've run out of ideas...

Comment: Looks like I don't have to write an answer anymore... this nails the deal. :)

Comment: @J. M. You flatter me. Thanks!

Comment: @jorgen: Appreciate the accept, perhaps you did not see *KennyColnago*'s follow-up answer? Unless you're specifically wanting to use GF (perhaps to generalize to some other cases), or need to do this for cases where the memory usage of his follow-up becomes prohibitive, it's a fast and clever answer. If this were *my* question, and the two mentioned items did not apply, *that's* the answer *I'd* accept...

Comment: @jorgen: Please check out the update... testing further, but looks... interesting.

Comment: So, how much of the $q$-literature have you waded into just for this question? :)

Comment: @J. M.: Enough to make it painfully obvious my combinatorics has become *very* rusty, but, I've not seen this derivation for this partition case before. Might need to swing by Persi's office for a sanity check...

Comment: I wish I understood this method but it has gone way over my head.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Happy to chat about it if you'd like - added a further neat optimization just now.. Wish I could bounty the question itself - provided several cigars worth of fun thinking...

Answer (score 18):

Here is a summary of comments (before @ciao's best answer above), with a change in notation. These functions calculate the number of partitions of `n` into exactly `k` distinct parts of size at most `m`.

```
NumberOfWays000[n_, k_, m_] := 
   Count[Map[Length,Map[DeleteDuplicates, IntegerPartitions[n,{k},Range[m]]]], k]

NumberOfWays001[n_, k_, m_] := 
   Total[Boole[Apply[Unequal, IntegerPartitions[n, {k}, Range[m]], 1]]]

NumberOfWays002[n_, k_, m_] := 
   Coefficient[Expand[Product[1 + t*z^j, {j, 1, m}]], t^k*z^n]

NumberOfWays003[n_, k_, m_] := 
   Coefficient[SeriesCoefficient[QPochhammer[-t*z, z, m], {z, 0, n}], t^k]

NumberOfWays004[n_, k_, m_] := 
   If[# =!= {n, k}, #, 0] &[{n, k} /. 
      CoefficientRules[Product[1 + t*z^j, {j, 1, m}], {z, t}]]
```

And some timings:

```
Block[{n = 50, kmax},
   kmax = Quotient[Sqrt[8 n + 1] - 1, 2];
   {AbsoluteTiming[Sum[NumberOfWays000[n, k, m], {k, 1, kmax}, {m, 1, n}]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Sum[NumberOfWays001[n, k, m], {k, 1, kmax}, {m, 1, n}]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Sum[NumberOfWays002[n, k, m], {k, 1, kmax}, {m, 1, n}]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Sum[NumberOfWays003[n, k, m], {k, 1, kmax}, {m, 1, n}]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Sum[NumberOfWays004[n, k, m], {k, 1, kmax}, {m, 1, n}]]}
]

(* {{2.462624, 109279}, {1.644974, 109279}, {19.891302, 109279},
    {9.002684, 109279}, {23.642686, 109279}} *)
```

A larger calculation with $n=107, k=11, m=100$ shows that methods based on `IntegerPartitions` slow dramatically to over `10 seconds`. `Methods 002, 003, 004` have timings of `1.5, 0.5, 1.8 s`, respectively, subject to warnings about caching, etc. by ciao. Code in the answer by ciao returns in just `0.17 s`.

Comment: Might want to add some test with large cases, since that's what op seems to be after, and any of the "counting" of massaged generated partitions that s/b fastest on small cases will utterly fail...

Comment: Also might want to add the expansion to method 001 as stated in comments...

Comment: @ciao  Is method 004 the rewrite of method 001 to which your refer? A large example added and, as you suggest, the methods dependent on `IntegerPartitions` approach an utter fail...

Comment: No, I meant taking the OP and going from `Coefficient[GenFuncy[m] , x^k*y^n]` to `Coefficient[GenFuncy[m] // Expand, x^k*y^n]` - that can speed things greatly. As an aside, use care in timings - MMA caches stuff from various coefficient & series functions, and I think some of it is opaque, that is, *not* cleared by `ClearSystemCache` etc. - I've found when benchmarking such things that running each case in a fresh kernel can lead to wildly differing results vs testing sequentially with `ClearSystemCache` interspersed....

Comment: Ok, added method 001a with `Expand`, which makes a huge increase in speed, as you were aware.

Comment: You don't need the extra `Function` in the last definition: `NumberOfWays005[n_, k_, m_] := 
  Coefficient[Product[1 + t*z^j, {j, 1, m}] // Expand, t^k*z^n]`

Answer (score 16):

Here is a totally different approach based on the fact that successive products forming the generating function are due to multiplication by a binomial $1+t*z^j$. Form a matrix $v$ of zeros with $n+1$ rows and $k+1$ columns. Initialize the top left corner to 1. Iterate $v=v+w$ where $w$ is the matrix $v$ shifted down by $j$ rows and to the right by 1. The element $v[[n+1,k+1]]$ after $m$ iterations is the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts of size at most $m$. It takes more memory, but is very fast.

```
DistinctPartitions2D[n_, k_, m_] :=
   Block[{n1 = n + 1, k1 = k + 1, v},
      v = ConstantArray[0, {n1, k1}];
      v[[1, 1]] = 1;
      Do[
         v = v + ArrayPad[v[[1 ;; n1 - j, 1 ;; k]], {{j,0}, {1,0}}],
         {j, 1, m}];
      v[[n1, k1]]
   ]
```

Some timings

```
AbsoluteTiming[DistinctPartitions2D[451, 29, 101]]
(* {0.010868, 231} *)

AbsoluteTiming[DistinctPartitions2D[3000, 30, 1729]]
(* {46.823481, 2704951781342880353088665158660429357} *)
```

**Update**

Clearly(!) @ciao's brilliant new code using `QBinomial` deserves his own bounty and the Accept. For large cases, it is orders of magnitude faster than `DistinctPartitions2D`. *Nolo contendere*. For example,

```
AbsoluteTiming[myDP[3000, 30, 1729]]
```

took about 1.5 s compared to 47 s for `DistinctPartitions2D` shown above. My method is slow because approximately 100000 array elements are added 1729 times, for about 161 million operations. ciao's case of

```
AbsoluteTiming[myDP[5050, 100, 5050]]
```

returned 1 in a fraction of a second, but `DistinctPartitions2D` would require about 2.6 billion operations. No need to benchmark a bunch of cases, math beats brute force every time. Well done.

Comment: Clever idea, +1 o/c. You can ~ double speed, mind if I add a derivation here or on mine?

Comment: @ciao I was secretly hoping you would have a go. Looking forward to it.

Comment: 100 rep points inbound - I for one appreciate the effort I know went into thinking through this. Well done. I'll get to mentioned optimization as soon as I have some time...

Comment: Very cleverly done! :) With a few modifications, I think this could even be compilable…

Comment: @ciao @J. M.  I've learned a lot from your contributions on this site. Thank you both for the kind words. I've edited the code to change k1-1 to just k. Also tried a version eliminating `ArrayPad`, that is, `v[[j + 1 ;;, 2 ;; k1]] += v[[1 ;; n1 - j, 1 ;; k]]`, but this is slightly slower.

Comment: @KennyColnago: Give the update in my answer a whirl, curious how it compares to yours on your machine for larger cases... on loungebook {300, 20, 200} was much faster, {1000, 30, 500} more so. Interesting...

Comment: Now that I think about it… what if you use `SparseArray[]` for this?

Comment: @J. M.: End result that coeff. is taken from is not sparse, and you'd pay to overhead of updating the zeroes along the way...e.g., for {1000,10,1000} case, only ~11% zeroes in end result. We think alike, though....

Comment: @KennyColnago: Any chance you might have time to update your benchie post with your array solution and my update, particularly for a smattering of big/really big cases? W/B interested to see comparison on your HW. Also, even if my update is faster, obviously the bounty is still going to you - your clever method motivated my re-thinking the problem, and is appreciated!

Comment: @ciao  Updated this post with a couple of comparisons of your amazing `QBinomial` code. Never heard of `QBinomial`, don't understand it, I've got some homework to do. Thanks!

Comment: @KennyColnago: Thanks for taking time to update, and for the most kind words there. As they say in late-night TV commercial land, "But wait! There's more!" - I figured out an optimization that nets performance gains to multiple orders of magnitude. Will post when I get back to cigar lounge...

Comment: 100 rep. bounty awarded, thanks again for prodding further thought on this interesting question.