# How to efficiently find all sets of primes that add to a given number?

Tags: number-theory, subset

For large numbers the naive approach falls down:

```
Select[Subsets[Range[1, 4]], PrimeQ@Total@# &]
```

> {{2},{3},{1,2},{1,4},{2,3},{3,4},{1,2,4}}

```
Subsets[Range[1, 50]]
```

> Subsets::toomany: "The number of subsets (1125899906842624) indicated
>   by...  is too large; it must be a machine integer"

Any suggestions?

Comment: `IntegerPartitions[#, All, Prime[Range@PrimePi@#]] &` - or do you mean sets with distinct elements?

Comment: @ciao sets in the mathy sense, so yes here sets have distinct elements.

Comment: You have 6000+ rep and still pasting images instead of code. OMG.

Comment: @M.R. In that case, `With[{ip = IntegerPartitions[#, All, Prime[Range@PrimePi@#]] &@#},
  Select[ip, Length@# == Length@DeleteDuplicates@# &]] &` ?

Comment: BTW, I note that what your title says, and what your example does, do not mesh - the example shows finding sets that sum to a prime. So, what is it you want, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll also assume the question wants sets of distinct primes summing to an integer n. Following on from the very informative discussion of distinct partitions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91613/improving-speed-of-code-computing-number-of-nonrepeating-partitions) (thank you @ciao!), I include the generating function vector update method below.

```
SumDistinctPrimes[n_] :=
   Block[{n1 = n + 1, v, t},
      v = ConstantArray[0, n1];
      v[[1]] = 1;
      Do[
         v[[p + 1 ;; n1]] += ToString[p]*v[[1 ;; n1 - p]],
         {p, Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]]}];  
      Map[ToExpression, 
          Apply[List, Apply[List, Expand[v[[n1]]]], 1], {2}]]
```

Each generating function binomial `1+"p"*z^p` is tagged by the unique string "p" corresponding to prime `p`, then `Apply` is used to change sums and products into lists of primes. Almost all the time is spent on `Expand[v[[n1]]]`, which perhaps someone could speed up...

Timings become faster than @ciao's `distPrimePart[n]` as `n` increases beyond about 250. Has @ciao got another brilliant `QBinomial` approach here?

Answer (score 9):

I'll assume the title reflects the goal, as opposed to the example. If this is not the case, comment and I'll delete.

```
distPrimePart[n_] := Module[{l = 1, p},
  Join @@ Reap[While[(p =Prime@Range@(PrimePi@(n - Tr@Prime@Range@(l - 1)))) != {},
      Sow[Select[IntegerPartitions[n, {l}, p], Length@# == Length@DeleteDuplicates@# &]];
      l++]][[2, 1]]];
```

much more efficient than my comment solution. Example use:

```
distPrimePart[25]
(* {{23, 2}, {17, 5, 3}, {13, 7, 5}, {13, 7, 3, 2}, {11, 7, 5, 2}} *)
```

I assume you know this is a *subset-sum* problem, making it $\scriptsize\mathcal{N}\mathcal{P}$-Complete, you're not going to do this "efficiently"...