# Algorithm too slow

Tags: performance-tuning, algorithm

Writing:

```
nn = 10;

Table[Sum[Length[Select[DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[
     {1, 2, 5, 10}, i]]], Total[#] == n &]], {i, 1, n}], {n, 1, nn}]
```

I get:

> {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11}

which is what I wanted!

Problem: for greater `nn` the algorithm is too slow and fails to generate the desired vector. Could someone make it leaner?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you are describing the classic problem of [counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) the number of ways to make change, given coins of value 1, 2, 5, and 10.

Generating functions can count the ways.

```
GFCoinPartitions[n_, d_List] := 
   Block[{z}, 
         Coefficient[Series[1/Times @@ (1 - z^d), {z, 0, n}], z, n]
   ]
```

For your case, the input list of denominations is `d={1,2,5,10}`, and `n` is the sum you want. For example,

```
Table[GFCoinPartitions[i,{1,2,5,10}],{i,1,10}]
```

> {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11}

If you really want some speed, then consider `SeriesCoefficient`.

```
messyexpression =
   SeriesCoefficient[
      1/((1 - z) (1 - z^2) (1 - z^5) (1 - z^10)),
      {z, 0, n}, Assumptions :> n > 0]
```

Use this as follows to get counts up to 120.

```
Round[messyexpression /. n -> Range[1, 120]]
```

Much, much faster is the rather arcane code below. This gives the first 120 counts in less than a millisecond.

```
Block[{n = 120, c, t},
   c = ConstantArray[1, n + 1];
   t = c;
   Do[
      Do[t[[Range[i + 1, n + 1]]] += c[[Range[n + 1 - i]]], {i, k, n, k}];
      c = t,
      {k, {2, 5, 10}}];
   c
]
```

Comment: I can suggest an improvement to your first method. Just take the series to degree 120 (or whatever) and the third element, the coefficient list, is the set of values of interest. Handles to 1000 in 0.15 seconds. Still much slower than the mystery method though.

Comment: Thanks @DanielLichtblau. By the way, the arcane method comes from the discussion of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91613/improving-speed-of-code-computing-number-of-nonrepeating-partitions) related question.

Comment: Interesting. I did notice that both methods scale quadratically. There may be a way to improve on that, some flavor of Newton iterations maybe.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [`FrobeniusSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve) for this:

```
Table[
    Length @ FrobeniusSolve[{1,2,5,10}, i],
    {i,10}
]
```

> {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11}

**Addendum**

@Kenny mentioned a [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) approach is also possible, but then showed that an "arcane" [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do) loop would be much faster if one wanted all values up to some threshold. On the other hand, if one is only interested in a single value, then the "messy" [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) approach would be much faster for large enough $n$. Here is the [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient) approach:

```
messyexpression = SeriesCoefficient[
    1/((1-z) (1-z^2) (1-z^5) (1-z^10)),
    {z,0,n},
    Assumptions:>n>0
];
messyexpression //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{20} \left(\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n}{5}+\frac{7}{5}}
>    \left(-3-(-1)^{2/5}+(-1)^{3/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right) \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3
>    \left(1-\sqrt[5]{-1}+(-1)^{2/5}\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{4/5} \left(-(-1)^{4/5}\right)^n
>    \left(-3-(-1)^{2/5}+(-1)^{3/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right) \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3
>    \left(1-\sqrt[5]{-1}+(-1)^{2/5}\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{\frac{3 n}{5}+\frac{4}{5}}
>    \left(3-\sqrt[5]{-1}+(-1)^{4/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)
>    \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3}-\frac{\left(-(-1)^{2/5}\right)^n
>    \left(3-\sqrt[5]{-1}+(-1)^{4/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)
>    \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3}\right)+\frac{(-1)^n}{10}+\frac{1}{100} \left(\frac{(-1)^{2/5}
>    \left(-\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^n \left(-17+30 \sqrt[5]{-1}-21 (-1)^{2/5}+21
>    (-1)^{3/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right) \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3
>    \left(1-\sqrt[5]{-1}+(-1)^{2/5}\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{2 n/5} \left(17-21 \sqrt[5]{-1}+30 (-1)^{2/5}+21
>    (-1)^{4/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right) \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3}-\frac{(-1)^{4/5}
>    \left(-(-1)^{3/5}\right)^n \left(17-21 \sqrt[5]{-1}-30 (-1)^{3/5}+21 (-1)^{4/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)
>    \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3}+\frac{(-1)^{\frac{4 n}{5}+\frac{4}{5}} \left(17+21 (-1)^{2/5}-21 (-1)^{3/5}+30
>    (-1)^{4/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right) \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3
>    \left(1-\sqrt[5]{-1}+(-1)^{2/5}\right)}\right)+\frac{1}{80} (-1)^n (n+1)+\frac{91 (n+1)}{400}+\frac{7}{200} (n+1)
>    (n+2)+\frac{1}{600} (n+1) (n+2) (n+3)+\frac{1}{10} \left(\frac{(-1)^{2/5} \left(-\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^n
>    \left(-(-1)^{3/5} n-n+2 (-1)^{4/5}-3 (-1)^{3/5}+3 (-1)^{2/5}-3 \sqrt[5]{-1}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)
>    \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^7 \left(1-\sqrt[5]{-1}+(-1)^{2/5}\right)^3}+\frac{(-1)^{\frac{2 n}{5}+\frac{6}{5}}
>    \left((-1)^{4/5} n-n+3 (-1)^{4/5}+(-1)^{2/5}\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3
>    \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^7}-\frac{(-1)^{2/5} \left(-(-1)^{3/5}\right)^n \left((-1)^{4/5} n+(-1)^{3/5}
>    n-\sqrt[5]{-1} n-n+(-1)^{4/5}+(-1)^{3/5}-2 (-1)^{2/5}-2 \sqrt[5]{-1}-2\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^2
>    \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^7}+\frac{(-1)^{\frac{4 n}{5}+\frac{1}{5}} \left(2 (-1)^{4/5} n-2 (-1)^{2/5}
>    n+\sqrt[5]{-1} n+n+11 (-1)^{4/5}-7 (-1)^{3/5}+5 (-1)^{2/5}-9 \sqrt[5]{-1}+12\right)}{\left(-1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^3
>    \left(1+\sqrt[5]{-1}\right)^7 \left(1-\sqrt[5]{-1}+(-1)^{2/5}\right)^3}\right)+\frac{21}{50}$

Comparing:

```
FullSimplify[messyexpression /. n->10^8] //AbsoluteTiming
TimeConstrained[
    Block[{n = 10^8, c, t},
        c = ConstantArray[1, n + 1];
        t = c;
        Do[
            Do[t[[Range[i + 1, n + 1]]] += c[[Range[n + 1 - i]]], {i, k, n, k}];
            c = t,
            {k, {2, 5, 10}}
        ];
        c
    ],
    10
]
```

> {0.190879, 1666667116666705000001}
>
> $Aborted

Moreover, it is possible to simplify `messyexpression` a bit as follows:

```
s = FullSimplify[
    Simplify[
        ComplexExpand[Re[messyexpression]] /. s_Sin | s_Cos :> FullSimplify[s]
    ],
    n \[Element] Integers
];
s //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{-\left(11 \sqrt{5}-25\right) (n+9) \left(2 n (n+18)+15 (-1)^n+97\right)+60 \sqrt{50-22 \sqrt{5}} \sin
>    \left(\frac{\pi  n}{5}\right)+\frac{24 \left(\left(160-6 \sqrt{5}\right) n+1271\right) \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi 
>    n}{5}\right)}{\sqrt{91325+40822 \sqrt{5}}}+120 \sqrt{1525-682 \sqrt{5}} \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi  n}{5}\right)-24
>    \sqrt{\frac{2}{669125+299231 \sqrt{5}}} \left(2 \left(80+3 \sqrt{5}\right) n+1271\right) \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi 
>    n}{5}\right)+60 \left(15-7 \sqrt{5}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{5}\right)-24 \left(2 \left(4 \sqrt{5}-9\right)
>    n+79 \sqrt{5}-178\right) \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{5}\right)+120 \left(9 \sqrt{5}-20\right) \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi 
>    n}{5}\right)+12 \left(\left(14-6 \sqrt{5}\right) n-73 \sqrt{5}+169\right) \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  n}{5}\right)}{1200
>    \left(11 \sqrt{5}-25\right)}$

The simplified form is a bit faster to compute:

```
Simplify[s /. n->10^15] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0124, 1666666666666711666666666667050000000000001}

Comment: This is a bit faster: `Total /@ Table[
  Length@IntegerPartitions[n, {i}, {1, 2, 5, 10}], {n, 1, nn}, {i, 1, 
   n}]`

Comment: @chuy That's a very good solution. I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can also take advantage of the function [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html) to avoid the unnecessary overhead of creating all of those tuples only to discard the ones that don't add up to $n$.

```
Total /@ Table[
  Length@IntegerPartitions[n, {i}, {1, 2, 5, 10}], {n, 1, nn}, {i, 1, 
   n}]
```

Now this still won't realistically get you up to `nn=1000`, for example on my machine I can get up to `400` in about 23 seconds.  For higher numbers @KennyColnago's solution is definitely the way to go.

Comment: The GF method by Kenny is neat, but I think this is the neatest one of the lot. The only change I would suggest is that you should use `Total[expr, {2}]` instead of `Total /@ expr`.